# Access Crystal Subreport without displaying it

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

In Crystal Reports 2016, I have set up a sub report and parent report.

The sub report holds the raw data and does some calculation

My parent report should then be a summary and additional calculations of the sub report, without displaying the full raw data which is overwhelming for the user.

However, I cannot find a way to link the variables / data to the parent report, without also displaying all of the data.

Is there a way to hide sub reports while maintaining access to the data - or an easier way to achieve what I am after?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a "On demand Subreport(Similar to hyperlink)"

Comment: This doesn't let my functions etc. access the data - I believe because the data isn't loaded until the hyperlink is followed?

Comment: There must be a common fields or parameter between parent report and subreport which will sort the data in subreport accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of questions trying to do what you want.  Most often the answer is that you can't do that.  If you want to tame the data that the user sees, can you do the work to get the data that you want, hide it in the main report, and then show only the subreport?  In essence, do it backwards to the way you want.